# Determining .dll dependencies in Visual Studio Express Edition C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have written a small program in C# in `Visual Studio Express 2008`. How do I determine which dll's this app requires, so that I could distribute it along with the required files?

Note:

> Visual Studio Express 2008 comes without the Modules Window
>   ('Debug->Windows->Modules').

Comment: Download one of the free decompiler, and then check which assemblies are referenced by it, http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler/features.aspx You only need to distribute what is outside of .NET Framework. mscorlib and so on are bundled with .NET Framework and you don't need to distribute them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Dependency Walker to determine dll dependencies.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/